# How to work on a large view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview

Hi I'm trying to understand how to work on a large view, because i'm doing a form view, I use a scrollable view, but here I can't add items bottom because I'm outside of the view, I learned it:

- select view controller in storyboard
- go to size inspector
- simulated size change fixed to freeform
- then set height of your view controller

But my view is designed as this:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmGCW.png]

Comment: Have you tried `ctrl` + dragging from the document outline itself?

Comment: I'd suggest to use a table view instead of scroll view, design the cells individually and manage them from code.

Comment: Why is the problem? are you saying that even after setting a custom size in the design time you still can add views to it?

Comment: I exactly use this approach and it works for me perfectly.

Comment: @IslamQ. Doesn't work

Comment: @hasan83 If I do this I have to resize de three views and then after resize of the initial height

Comment: do you mean the resize of the viewcontroller main view, the scrollview and the scrollview content view? I still don't see where is the problem!

Comment: The display you see in the interface builder is only for the design time. on runtime the controller view will be resized to match the device screen. You don't have to resize the views to the original heights. do you use constraints? it will not work anyway if you don't use constraints because devices have deferent heights.

Comment: @hasan83 I think I did a mistake when I did the view I'm gonna follow this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9bS7H-mYe4

Answer (score 0):

Best way (in my opinion) is to add the view content in code.

Comment: Add the scrollView in the class, then add the content to the scrollView 'scrollView.addSubview.yourContent'

Comment: this is an old way to handle scrollview content. now it can be handled by using constraints.

Comment: you do that by setting the four top, right, bottom left constraint of the scrollview to its parent view. and then for the scrollview inner view set left, top and bottom constraints to the scrollview and an equal width to the scrollview.

Comment: As hasan83 added the constraints do have to be added when doing it in code. From my understanding the poblem is that the 3 views are larger than the viewable scrollView in IB which is a pain in the butt! I had a project like this and found it much easier to do it in code.